# Firemonkey MacOS app - Close vs Quit

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I have developed a MacOS application using Firemonkey XE8 and I have noticed that the X button of the main form actually terminates the application instead of hiding/minimizing it as it is the default behavior in most of the MacOS apps.

To solve this issue I have added the following logic in the FormCloseQuery to minimize the app if someone click the X button:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin


{$IFDEF MACOS}
 if (Self.WindowState<>TWindowState.wsMinimized) then begin
  Self.WindowState:=TWindowState.wsMinimized;
  CanClose:=false;
 end
 else
  CanClose:=true;
{$ENDIF MACOS}


end;
```

This works but the side effect is that if someone right click the application in the Dock and select Quit, the application will be minimized if the form is not already minimized. So the user should click Quit two times to really close the app.

Is there any way to fix this? The close button should hide/minimize the window and the Quit should terminate the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't have apple computer but i've tested this code on Windows, it works. 
(XE2 FM app)

```
uses
  fmx.platform

procedure TForm2.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
 var
  p:TPointF;
begin
  p := Platform.GetMousePos;
  p := ScreenToClient(p);

  if p.Y > 0 then
    CanClose := True
  else
    begin
     Self.WindowState:=TWindowState.wsMinimized;
     CanClose:=false;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: To get the mouse position In XE8 I used Screen.MousePos instead of Platform.GetMousePos. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is **not** different.

- Closing the "MainForm" will terminate the application
- Closing a "SubForm" will just close that form

You just notice this behaviour on MacOS from *multiple document applications* (comparable to MDI known from Windows).

Comment: I think even the MainForm should not close the application. Only small utility programs closes when you close the main form, while e.g. the included "Mail" program does not close. The Mail program is not a multiple document application because there is no purpose in opening the same list of mail folder multiple times.

Comment: In a way also Mail is. You can open new Windows in Mail for a different view on your Mailbox. So the behaviour here is the same as multiple documents.